# (C) printf returns only 0.(0) with %lf

Tags: c, printf

Please, explain me why printf in for cycles returns only 0.00000
and min is an enormous big value. Tried to use `float` and `%f`, but it returns only nan.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>

double getMin (double xf,double yf,double zf)
{
    if (xf < yf && xf < zf)
    {
        return (xf);
    }
    else if (yf < xf && yf < zf)
    {
        return (yf);
    }
    else return (zf);
}

int main()
{
    double getMin (double xf,double yf,double zf);
    double x = 1, y = 0,  z = 1, min = 0;
    for (int j = 3 ; j >= -2 ; j--)
    {
        x = (sin(pow(j, (1 / 2))) / (j + 1)) * x;
        printf("\nP #1=%lf", x);
    }

    for (int k = 5 ; k <= 9 ; k++)
    {
        y = cos(k / (k - 10)) + y;
        printf("\nS #1 = %lf", y);
    }

    for (int l = 2 ; l <= 8 ; l++)
    {
        z = (log10(l - 4)) * z;
        printf("\nP #2= %lf", z);
    }
    min = getMin(x, y, z);
    printf("\nM = %lf", min);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: `1/2` is an integer division and evaluates to `0`

Comment: Ditto `k / (k - 10)` is an integer computation.

Comment: `printf` doesn't "return" `0.000000`, but _prints_ it. `printf`'s return value means something different and is of type `int`.

Comment: Does this mean i need to use `double` instead `int k = 5`?

Comment: No, `k` is the loop variable, so should be an `int`. Just change `(k - 10)` to `(k - 10.0)`. When one of the arguments to a binary operator is a double, then the other is promoted to double and the result is a double. The compiler will treat `10.0` as a double whereas `10` is an int.

Comment: Better to cast to `double` than use `double` in a loop. Because of imprecise values, the loop end condition might not work.

Comment: What exactly is this code supposed to be calculating?  Knowing that will help us help you.

Comment: tried to change (k-10) to (k-10.0) didn't help.
the code should calculate 3 math rows and find minimum

Comment: Even using double for the second argument of pow with (1 / 2 ) will be NaN when the first argument (j)  is negative. I think your equation is not correct even with proper types.

Comment: What does "3 math rows" mean?  What specifically are you attempting to calculate?

Comment: Although it is probably not your issue, do note that your `getMin()` function is broken.  Check, for example, `getMin(1.0, 1.0, 2.0)`.

Comment: At one iteration of your first loop, `j` takes the value `-1`.  In that iteration you perform a division by `0`.

Comment: In several iterations of your third loop, `l` takes a value less than or equal to `4`.  In those iterations you attempt to compute the logarithm of a non-positive number.

Comment: You may find `"%e"` more informative that `"%f"`.

Comment: `printf` format for `double` is `%f`, not `%lf` where the `l` modifier will at best be ignored.

Comment: function declaration for `getMin` with local scope in `main` is both useless since it is defined at global scope before and a very bad idea.

Comment: in general, when writing code, for readability, understandability and ease of documentation, only one statement per line and only 0 or 1 variable declaration per statement.  When writing 'double' literals/constants, write them  as double values I.E. '1.0' rather than as integer values I.E. '1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues in you code.

- You mix integer arithmetic and floating point arithmetic.  `1 / 2` evaluates to `0`, whereas `1. / 2` evaluates to `0.5`.  Similarly, you must write `k / (k - 10.)` if you want floating point arithmetic.
- the `printf` format for `double` is `%f`, not `%lf`.  The `l` will hopefully just be ignored. It is on my system, but maybe it does something fishy in your environment.  `printf` formats are inconsistent with `scanf` formats: one more reason to avoid using `scanf`.
- redeclaration of `getMin` at local scope in `main` is useless and bad practice.
- In the first loop, you compute `pow(j, (1 / 2))`.  You probably mean `pow(j, 0.5)` which is the same as `sqrt(j)`.  Yet `j` takes the values `-1` and `-2`, yielding `nan` as expected, `pow(j, 0.5)` computes the square root in the real domain, not the complex domain.
- Computing `log(l - 4)` for `l=2` also returns `nan` because `log` is undefined for negative values.

With these fixes, executing your code gives this output:

```
P #1=0.246757
P #1=0.081246
P #1=0.034183
P #1=0.000000
P #1=nan
P #1=nan
S #1 = 0.540302
S #1 = 0.611040
S #1 = -0.079719
S #1 = -0.733362
S #1 = -1.644493
P #2= nan
P #2= nan
P #2= nan
P #2= nan
P #2= nan
P #2= nan
P #2= nan
M = nan
```

Which does not seem incorrect to me: `nan < x` and `x < nan` always evaluate to false, therefore `getMin(nan, y, nan)` returns `nan`.

Answer (score 0):

Using this code, which is the same as your posted code, with the addition of some spacing in the output and correction in the layout of the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
//#include <conio.h>

double getMin (double xf,double yf,double zf);


int main( void )
{

    double x = 1.0;
    double y = 0.0;
    double z = 1.0;
    double min = 0.0;

    for (int j = 3 ; j >= -2 ; j--)
    {
        x = (sin(pow(j, (1 / 2))) / (j + 1)) * x;
        printf("\nP #1=%lf", x);
    }

    printf( "\n\n" );

    for (int k = 5 ; k <= 9 ; k++)
    {
        y = cos(k / (k - 10)) + y;
        printf("\nS #1 = %lf", y);
    }

    printf( "\n\n" );

    for (int l = 2 ; l <= 8 ; l++)
    {
        z = (log10(l - 4)) * z;
        printf("\nP #2= %lf", z);
    }

    printf( "\n\n" );

    min = getMin(x, y, z);
    printf("\nM = %lf", min);
    getchar();
} // end function: main


double getMin (double xf,double yf,double zf)
{
    if (xf < yf && xf < zf)
    {
        return (xf);
    }
    else if (yf < xf && yf < zf)
    {
        return (yf);
    }
    else return (zf);
} // end function: getMin
```

results in this output:

```
P #1=0.059006
P #1=0.024826
P #1=0.020890
P #1=inf
P #1=-inf


S #1 = 0.540302
S #1 = 1.080605
S #1 = 0.664458
S #1 = 0.010814
S #1 = -0.900316


P #2= nan
P #2= nan
P #2= nan
P #2= nan
P #2= nan
P #2= nan
P #2= nan


M = nan
```

The reasons for the output are:

these kind of expressions: (1 / 2)  are integer expressions. this one will evaluate to 0, as integers cannot have fractions.

excerpt from man page for pow() "If x is a finite value less than 0, and y is a finite noninteger, a domain error occurs, and a NaN is returned."

excerpt from man page for log10 (and log()) " If x is a NaN, a NaN is returned. If x is 1, the result is +0. If x is positive infinity, positive infinity is returned. If x is zero, then a pole error occurs, and the functions return -HUGE_VAL, -HUGE_VALF, or -HUGE_VALL, respectively. If x is negative (including negative infinity), then a domain error occurs, and a NaN (not a number) is returned."

the call to `getMin()` is being passed `-inf`, `-0.900316` and `nan` which are each being treated as valid double numbers,  so a `nan` is returned.

The above paragraphs explain why the outputs are as indicated.

Strongly suggest reading/understanding those system functions that are being called in your code.